# hanging a load from engineered I-joist ceiling

Tags: framing, joists

I'm trying to figure out the best method to hang a light 4x8 trailer that weighs just under 300lbs from my garage ceiling to store it.  I'm planning to use a light electric hoist or ratcheting hand winch to lift it, rigged with pulleys above the 4 corners of the trailer + safety chains once it's lifted into place.  The garage ceiling is finished with drywall.

My question is about how to attach the weight bearing pulleys to the ceiling, which is made of engineered i-joists spaced 24" oc.  My garage ceiling is also the floor of a bedroom, so I don't have easy access from above to put a support beam across several joists.  The height of each i-joist (the space between garage ceiling and bedroom floor) is about 30 inches or so.

I'm considering three options:

1) attach two 2x6x10' spanning 4 joists each, one at the front and one at the back of the trailer, and attach the weight bearing pulleys to the 2x6 above each corner of the trailer.  Each 2x6 would be attached with two 1/4" lags to each i-joist (total of 8 lags in each 2x6).

2) remove the drywall and install 2x6 (or 2x8) blocking between the joists, hung to the joist webbing using galvanized joist hangers, then attach the pulleys to the blocking.

3) same as #1 but using 1 5/8" x 1 5/8" unistrut instead of 2x6, which would mean only one lag into each i-joist.

Is there one method that is better or worse than the others?  #2 is much more work since it involves removing large sections of drywall, but I'm not sure whether that's a more secure method than the others.

Thanks for any advice you can offer!

Comment: Wow...are you sure it’s about 30” from upper floor to ceiling below. I’ve never seen a 30” I-Joist. Maybe you should take a picture of that space. If there are two I-Joists stacked on top of each other in that 30” space, that would be good to know